# NP problem implications

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Hi, i would like to have some clarification on NP-completeness.
In particular I'm reading an article where they show:

1) Partitioning the edges of a graph into connected component of 3 edges (3-path or triangles or $K_{1,3}$) is NP-complete.

2) Partitioning the edges of a graph into subgraph isomorphic to 3-path is NP-complete

3) Partitioning the edges of a graph into subgraph isomorphic to K_1,3 is NP-complete.

What I don't understand is why 1) doesn't imply 2) and 3)
If I can't tell if partitioning a graph with subgraph isomorphic to a connected component of 3 edges is possible or not, then I can't even tell if partitioning with subgraph isomorphic (for example) to 3-path is possible or not.
Thak you for your help

Comment: If you know that a graph cannot be partitioned into 3-paths, how does it help you to determine whether it can be partitioned into 3-edge components?

Comment: you're right, but if I know that I can't find any partition of 3 edge connected component then I'm sure that I can't find a partition with 3-paths (which are 3 edge connected component) 
So, 1)----->2) 

Comment: But if you *can* find a 3-edge partition, you have no information on the existence of 3-paths partition. A reduction has to be if and only if, otherwise it is useless. Let me give another example: 1') 3-colourability of graphs is NP-complete. If a graph has no 3-colouring, it has no 2-colouring either, hence by your logic, 2') 2-colourability of graphs is NP-complete. But this is wrong (unless P = NP), as 2-colourability is decidable in polynomial time.

Comment: Anyway, this is not a research-level question, and as such it is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help, and excuse me if I posted the question in the wrong site, I don't know any other.
Thank you again.

Comment: That could be http://math.stackexchange.com/ but there are many other as well